# Execute task after transaction ends - Grails

Tags: grails, transactions

I need to execute some tasks after grails transaction ends. I'm not looking for afterCommit of Hibernate, instead of that, I need a method to be called after the transaction of the service ends.

Is there any way? I've read the documentation but I couldn't find anything, just normal events like afterUpdate or afterCommit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the current session

`sessionFactory.currentSession.addEventListener(...)`

```
class MyListener extends BaseSessionEventListener {
    @Override
    void transactionCompletion(boolean successful) {

    }
}
```

You just need to verify the transaction was successful via the parameter. Also understand that if there are multiple transactions in a single session the listener will be invoked for each one.

Answer (score -2):

That really depends on what you're trying to do.  The best bet is probably to call a `@Transactional` method on a service, and then when that returns, run the code that you need to happen after the transaction.

An alternative, if you just want to spin off some task to do something simple, you can use:

```
new java.util.Timer().runAfter(1000) { //time in milliseconds
  //code to run here
}
```

This is just a shortcut to spin off a new thread and runs the closure body after (in the above example) 1 second...  I believe the closure still has access to injected grails objects, but does not have access to the session.  I'd double-check that though.   I've used this in several places for sending notifications that needed to wait until after some processing inside a transaction ended.